# Has Moon Knight been hinted at in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier, the-defenders-2017

[This article from Film School Rejects](https://filmschoolrejects.com/whats-next-for-the-marvel-cinematic-universe/) says the following:

> The Marvel Cinematic Universe has taken obscure properties like Guardians of the Galaxy and Ant-Man and turned them into blockbusters. One of the hardcore fans’ more requested lesser-known characters to enter the fray has been Marc Spector, aka Moon Knight. There have been hints of his existence in Captain America: The Winter Solider and Netflix’s The Defenders, yet there hasn’t been any news of him being introduced beyond an Easter egg.

I re-watched *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* to see if I could spot the reference, but I didn't. I even paused and read all the names that the helicarriers target for extermination during the final battle to see if they slipped in a "Marc Spector" or a "Steven Grant" somewhere, but I didn't see it. I wasn't quite willing to re-watch all eight hours of *The Defenders* to look for a reference, but I didn't remember anything obvious.

Are there actually references to Moon Knight in these (or any other) Marvel Cinematic Universe properties?

Comment: Did you try to google it? There seems to be an obscure (at least to me, since I don't read comics) reference to Moon Knight as "a TV anchor in Cairo" during a briefing by Agent Sitwell in *Winter Soldier*. See this question too: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19214/which-marvel-character-is-some-guy-from-egypt/24793

Comment: @Taladris Marc Spector was a mercenary, not a TV anchor, so I never would have connected that with Moon Knight just because it's in Cairo, and I'm not sure I buy that as a real Easter egg. [This article](https://uproxx.com/tv/defenders-teaser-easter-egg/3/) claiming a _Defenders_ Easter egg seems really tenuous too.

Comment: @Torisuda: Indeed. It was as a TV Producer that he's worked. (http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marc_Spector_(Earth-616)#The_One-Man_Avenger)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks, didn't know that. I'm still unlearned when it comes to Moon Knight.

Answer (score 2):

**There has been no reference to Moon Knight in any MCU property as of January 2022.** However, there is an upcoming television series *Moon Knight* that will be released later this year that will follow the character of Moon Knight (played by Oscar Isaac). *(It is possible that there will be a reference or two within mid- or after-credits scenes in upcoming films prior to the show's release, as has been done with other titles and characters.)*

Answer (score -5):

In *The Winter Soldier*, the accountant Jasper Sitwell  (then a Hydra member) is questioned by Cap, Black Widow and Falcon about the targets of Project Insight.

Sitwell’s answer was something like: "You. TV anchor in Cairo. Undersecretary of Defense. High school valedictorian in Iowa City. Bruce Banner. Stephen Strange. Anyone who's a threat to Hydra".

There's a speculation that the 'TV anchor' mentioned is Moon knight, but I personally don't think so, only because he's in Egypt. Here's why:

1. The targets of Hydra don't have to be a superhero, because they'll kill anybody who is a threat to Hydra in the future or now, from a high school student, to basically anyone.
2. TV anchor in Cairo could be an anchor who could have (or will) found something to expose or stop Hydra.
3. Undersecretary of Defense has a power to make right and bring Hydra down.
4. The high school valedictorian could be someone who is going to be recruited by a special agent to stop Hydra.

So, basically the big point of throwing these lines off is **to mention Stephen Strange**. Our own **Dr Strange**, as you mentioned, MCU likes to foreshadow and give hints or easter egg. When this movie came out, Dr Strange movie came out 2 years after. **Looks like he's one of the future threats that the Hydra algorithm found.**

Comment: Hello and welcome, I see you've posted a few answers here recently and a few have received some positive attention. The points you raise has been addressed by the OP in the comments, for which they have (as you have) stated it seems a stretch. You then go on to discuss completely unrelated information to the question which is asking about easter eggs involving Moon Knight. Can I suggest you [edit] your question to try and focus it more on the specific question at hand?